# How to determine when two objects are touching after an update?

Tags: java, android, box2d

I am using Box2D extension with AndEngine and right now I am having trouble determining whether or not two objects are touching. To help demonstrate I have a drawing:

[image: Two objects touching before and after an update]

I have the two objects touching and they are both in the same state. However, after something happens, one of them changes state. However, I cannot use a contact event to determine whether or not they are touching because contact events are only called when objects collide at that instant and when they stop colliding, so how do I tell if these two objects are touching when they have already had their first collision together?

While writing this I got an idea however I'm not entirely sure if it would work (am about to start testing it) and I want to see if there is a simpler solution

Comment: As you said, "contact events are called when objects collide and when they stop colliding" so you just need to keep track of that state yourself, eg. a boolean variable :)

Comment: Thats what my idea was, I created an array list of objects which when an object touched another, they both added each other to the array list and when they stopped the were removed... I haven't been able to test it yet because I just had my tonsils out XD

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea. Ouch! get better soon!